# Why my code doesn't delete the $_SESSION variable?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have a file where the `$_SESSION['username']` variable is first created:

```
 <?php

$kullaniciadi = $_POST['kullaniciadi'];
$sifre = $_POST['sifre'];

if ((!$kullaniciadi =="") and (!$sifre =="")) {
include("db.php");

$sql = $sqlt->query("select * from uye where kullaniciadi='$kullaniciadi' and sifre='".md5($sifre)."'");
$kayitsayisi = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if ($kayitsayisi == "0") {
header ("Location: login.php?hata=yes");

}

 else {

$kontrol_ok = $sql -> fetch_assoc();
$k=$kontrol_ok["kullaniciadi"];

session_start();

$_SESSION['username']= $k;

header ("Location: homepage.php");
}
}
else {
header ("Location: login.php?hata=yes");
}
?>
```

It is called `login_do.php` (I send MySQL data from `login.php` form to here, and do the username and password check in this file).

Than in every other PHP file I have, I begin with:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
echo 'loginok';
} else {
header ("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

Than I have a `logout.php`, where the user is redirected to if he presses a button. `logout.php` file contains this:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
}

session_destroy();

header("Location: login.php")

?>
```

But it simply doesn't work. I mean if I go into my browsers cookies and delete the SESSION cookie by myself, than yes, the whole system works and I can't access any other php files than `login.php` unless I log in. But I need this to work with logout.php instead of me deleting the session from the browser by myself manually.

Comment: I think that the `session_destroy()` part will prevent the `unset` part from working since PHP serializes the session at the end of the request and by that time it's been destroyed. In that case, when you start it again it will load the previous session data which contain `$_SESSION['username']`

Comment: Also tried the same code without session_destroy(), it doesn't work. It drives me crazy. What mistake am I doing here.

Comment: Worth mentioning here that your "login_do.php"  will always set the $_SESSION['username'] regardless of success.

Comment: I updated the login_do.php, file. I think it might be because I gave you a cut version of it that you think so. Why else would it always set the session variable.

Answer (score -1):

session_unset();

> > session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called.
> >
> > In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

--http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: hi, i tried: the exact code example they give in the url you gave me. I didnt even bother to change any variables, as the code was to destroy all session data. but it still didn't work.

Comment: Its working for me now, exactly like that with session_unset().  I don't know what's with the negativity.  I tested the code and posted it.

Comment: I am not the one who voted negatively for you. I am not high rank enough to vote for anyone. But the code doesn't fix my issue. Do you have an idea why it possibly doesn't delete my session variable?

Comment: header ("Location: login.php?hata=yes"); ?  are we setting the login to true with a get variable which is sticking in the browser location?  Honestly I've never seen this method of user verification. maybe try a different one.  sorry I couldn't be more help.